# data before 12 am

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How to  pull the data before midnight example  for today's date: `2019-10-14 23:59:47.577` from a stored procedure which runs in the morning 5 am. It should exclude any data after 12 in the midnight .

tried `DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()-1)` function, it works fine if i run manually without putting in the stored procedure which run at 5 am.

I'm happy to provide more information if it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a cutoff of midnight, I would recommend:

```
where datecol < convert(date, getdate())
```

This should be fine in a stored procedure or outside one.

Note:  This uses the server time, so it assumes that your definition of the date is based on what the server says (which could be in a different time zone).

Comment: Thanks for this, i will put this in the stored procedure today and will let you know the outcome.

Comment: Hi, I would like to get data before 11 pm now, can you help please?

Comment: @SindhuB . . . Ask another question.  Explain what to do with the period from 11pm to midnight.  Sample data and desired results are recommended.